# Proguard - how to keep all files a JAR uses?

Tags: android, proguard

I have manually added a JAR to my project. It uses lots of classes with different prefixes and I can't search and add all of them to my proguard file.
Is there a way to keep all the file the jar uses? The jar is called `nano-0.7.0.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a package name in your jar file? If you have, try `-keep class yourpackageName.**{*;}` to tell proguard system keep all the classes in your package, and then add `-dontwarn yourpackageName.**` to tell proguard system do not warning if the system can't find the class referenced by the class in your package.